# Updating an object store record in indexedDB using references only?

Tags: indexeddb

When updating records in indexedDB that contain arrays/objects, it appears that, perhaps the cloning step, uses the data referred to without requiring iterating through the values/properties. Is that reliable or should the assignments be performed explicitly?

For example, in the code below, assignment to `r.array` stores `array_from_RAM` whether assigned as a reference or using `forEach`.  Is using `forEach` to iterate repeating work that the browser will always perform regardless or can that not be relied upon such that the assignment should be performed as would be done if indexedDB was not involved.

Thank you.

```
 req = os.get( key );
 req.onsuccess = function()
  {
   if ( req.result )
    {
      r = req.result;
      r.array = array_from_RAM;
      array_from_RAM.forEach( ( v, i ) => { r.array[i] = v; } );
      os.put( r );
     };
   };
```

Comment: indexeddb clones on write, so manually copying properties in memory before the write is a waste

Comment: Thank you. I thought so but don't know enough about the background processes to be sure.